# How can I rename the manifest package of a certain apk?

Tags: android, aapt

I have an apk called testapp.apk and I want to rename the manifest package of that apk. I tried using `aapt testapp.apk --rename-manifest-package com.testapp` but it returned the usage instructions.

Comment: So are you using Eclipse? Is this your app that you're building and have the source code of, or do you not have the source code?

Comment: I have the source, but I don't want to change it in eclipse. I want to change the manifest-package of the apk.

Answer (score 0):

1 Open the AndroidManifest.xml file.

2 Position the cursor at the package attribute of the manifest element and choose Refactor Rename on the context menu.

3 In the Rename dialog box that opens, specify the new package name and click OK.

The value of the package attribute changes to the newly specified. However, because this does not cause renaming the parent Java package of the application class, the relative names of the application and activities are replaced with their fully qualified names.

Font: [Here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/renaming-an-application-package-%28application-id%29.html)
The same to Eclipse

Comment: I want to change the manifest package after the project being compiled. Thanks, I should have been more clear when asking the question.